# Can a body have a charge of $0.8 × 10^{-19}\:\rm C$? Why or Why not?

Tags: charge

Can a body have a charge of $0.8 × 10^{-19}\:\rm C$? Why or Why not?

Please answer. Justify why and why not.

Comment: @Chris, StephenG, Dvij Mankad, ZeroTheHero: I think, the question is not off-topic, and interesting answers can be given. In fact, this question is relevant in certain fields of experimental research.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Any particular reason you chose to completely change the meaning of the post (by introducing a gratuitous factor of $10^{38}$) when you edited it?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty dropping the minus sign seems to be more of an accident than malice to me. Also, if you're going to complain about editing, one might inquire why you [use a deprecated command](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd) in `\rm`.

Comment: @KyleKanos Indeed it looks like an accident, but the fact remains that through lack of care, the edit made the question utterly meaningless. As for the choice of `\rm`, it's easy - titles are sometimes displayed in environments without MathJax, so the minimally-intrusive choice wins out.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty yes, it was a careless mistake, and it does render the query meaningless. `-19}$ C` is even *less* intrusive and can be displayed nicely in mathjax-free environments (and would match the text fonts as well!)

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm not sure that that is worth arguing over.

Comment: I think the question is 'can a particle have charge $e/2$, half the electronic charge? '  After all, quarks have charge $e/3$, one third of the electronic charge. To which one has to say: there is no such particle in the standard model, but a more complicated beyond-the-standard-model model could include such particles.  It would have to be quite a long way beyond the standard model, and I don't know of any such.

Comment: My mistake, my deepest apologies. As Kyle correctly guessed, it was a careless accident. Always a fan of the irony in your comments Emilio ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such particles have not been observed and also are not part of the standard model. Quarks are theorised to have fractional charge and also quasiparticles have been observed with partial charge. None of these have e/2 and it is debatable if any of these qualify as particle. See https://physicsworld.com/a/fractional-charge-carriers-discovered/.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/251038)

Comment: @GiorgioP It does answer the question.

Comment: I agree with your statement: there is no particle in the standard model having a charge of $e/2$. However, you can understand the question also in a different way. For example: if you apply a tiny voltage between two capacitor plates, can one of the plates have a net charge of $e/2$? Here we talk about average charge, and the answer is a clear yes.

Comment: I do not know objects qualified as 'body" in the SM. Moreover there is much more physics out there than in the SM. Fractional electronic charges have been measured in quasi-particles in condensed matter. Therefore, writing that in a particular area of physics they have not been observed does not answer the question if a body may have a charge $e/2$.

Comment: @GiorgioP If you have a different or more complete answer, then you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what you call a ‘body’. If the body is completely decoupled from the rest of the world, it cannot have a fraction of the elementary charge.

If the body is an object coupled to something else, this may happen. Consider, for example, a H$_2^+$ molecule, i.e., a positively charged hydrogen molecule. It has one electron of charge $-e$ and two protons of charge $+e$, its total charge being $+e$. The electron is equally shared between the two proton nuclei in the quantum mechanical ground state. If we consider one of the two hydrogens to be the ‘object’ of interest, then it has a net charge of ‘+e/2’.

Comment: This is not physics.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you be more specific with your criticism?

Comment: This is physics. Look up: chemistry partial charge.